# How do I group a div in some class on MySQL while

Tags: php, while-loop

I want add a different class on my MySQL result.

```
<?php while ($fetch = $db->fetch($query)) { ?>
<div class="result"><?php echo $fetch['title']; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Output should be like this

```
<div class="group">
  <div class="result">Title</div>
  <div class="result">Title</div>
  <div class="result">Title</div>
  <div class="result">Title</div>
  <div class="result">Title</div>
  <div class="result">Title</div>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <div class="result">Title</div>
  <div class="result">Title</div>
  <div class="result">Title</div>
  <div class="result">Title</div>
  <div class="result">Title</div>
  <div class="result">Title</div>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <div class="result">Title</div>
  <div class="result">Title</div>
  <div class="result">Title</div>
</div>
```

Here, every 6 results will have `<div class="group"></div>`.

Let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a counter that increments every time the loop is ran, then at the beginning of each loop check the value.  if the value == 6 then close the current div and open a new one with the class change (you could make 2 counters to flip flop back and forth).  Reset your counter after the div change.

--edit added code--

Make yourself 2 'group' div classes, 'group1' and 'group0' for the flip-flop

```
<div class="group1">
<?php
$count = 0;
$divstyle = 1;
while ($fetch = $db->fetch($query)) {
    if (++$count == 6) {
        echo '</div><div class="group'.(++$divstyle % 2).'">';
        $count = 0;
    }
    echo '<div class="result">' . $fetch['title'] . '</div>';
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Why was this marked as the answer?  The OP didn't ask for a different class for every group.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="group">
<?php
$count = 0;
while ($fetch = $db->fetch($query)) {
    if (++$count == 6) {
        echo '</div><div class="group">';
        $count = 0;
    }
    echo '<div class="result">' . $fetch['title'] . '</div>';
}
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit bad...

```
<?php $cnt=0;while ($fetch = $db->fetch($query)) { ?>
<div class="result"><?php if($cnt%6==0){echo "<div class=\"group\">";} echo $fetch['title'];if($cnt%6==0){echo "</div>";} $cnt++;?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I take back the first comment, but I stand by the $cnt++%6. Just saw you never opened the div first.